# MinGW GDB (v7.6.1) - (gdb) Exception condition detected on fd 0

Tags: c++, gdb, g++, mingw

I have a very simple C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int i = 0;
  cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
  i++;
}
```

When I compile + link with debug using:

`---jGRASP exec: C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g -o hello-world-debug.exe hello-world-debug.cpp`

I get a success message and see the `hello-world-debug.exe` output file.  However, when I try to debug it using:

`----jGRASP exec: C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe --args C:\Users\ituser\Documents\hello-world-debug.exe`

I get the following:

> GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
>   Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
>   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
>   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
>   and "show warranty" for details.
>   This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
>   For bug reporting instructions, please see:
>   http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/...
>   Reading symbols from C:\Users\ituser\Documents\hello-world-debug.exe...done.
>   (gdb) Exception condition detected on fd 0
>   error detected on stdin
>    ----jGRASP: operation complete.

This is Windows 7.  Any ideas?

Comment: That might be an issue with the --args, can you add gdb to your path, `cd` into C:\Users\ituser\Documents and run `$gdb hello-world-debug.exe` ?

Comment: Indeed @AndyM , this did get me to a different error about a missing dll.  This certainly lets me know where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

A likely explanation of this error is given here:
https://mingw-users.narkive.com/p1rTitWk/exception-condition-detected-on-fd-0-error-detected-on-stdin

Quote:

> Howdy List,
>
> I have found what causes this Exception! After some painful tracing
> through all the running threads I have traced the culprit to this
> situation:
>
> If your program is blocked on stdin read, i.e. using std::cin or gets,
> and the program gets interrupted so that gdb takes over you will get
> this error! I have attached a simple program that will do this.
> Basically, it contains two threads, the main thread spawns a new
> thread then blocks on stdin. The new thread sleeps for a seconds than
> causes a segmentation fault crash.
>
> GDB takes over, but stdin is still being held by the program, so gdb
> cannot use it! Hence the exception!
>
> Thankies ^^
> -San Saeteurn